# Laravel 5.5 - Required jQuery/Javascript plugins can't be found

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

Im using `require` to include Javascript plugins for my project, but for some reason, the plugins cant be found by the browser. Starting `npm run dev` will compile all the scripts I need(scripts also located in the compiled file), but when running the project in the browser, it simply wont work.

> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: $(...).datepicker is
>   not a function"

Here my files:

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted: function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  }
});
```

bootstrap.js

```
window._ = require('lodash');


try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    require('bootstrap');

    window.datepicker = require('jquery-datepicker');

} catch (e) {}


window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

webpack.mix.js

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
      .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a solution by myself by following these instructions..

https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/master/docs/jquery-ui.md

You have to do it like this in your app.js

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;

import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker.js';
```

Now you can call the libray in your prefered way.

I guess this should work for other JS librays too..